# Eigenvalue proof with complicated matrix formula

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, determinant

This is a multipart linear algebra textbook question. Let $A, P_1, P_2, N_1, N_2$ be $n$ × $n$ matrices with real entries such that
$$
I_n= (t I_n − A) \left(\frac{N_1}{(t-1)^3} + \frac{N_2}{(t-1)^2} + \frac{P_1}{(t-1)} + \frac{P_2}{(t-2)}\right).
$$

Then, I'm asked to show the following:

1. If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $\lambda\in\{1, 2\}$.

I'm not really sure what my first steps here should be. Given the initial equation, I don't really know what matrix algebra I can apply. I'm wondering first of all how I can even take the determinant of both sides to connect it to eigenvalues

Any assistance on this question would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can also use determinants like you wanted. Just take the determinant of both sides, use the fact that the determinant of a product is the product of the determinants, and finally the fact that $1=xy$ implies $x \neq 0$.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson But how do we take the determinant of the massive sum of matrices? Is there any identity for that? I don't believe there is...

Comment: You don't have to expand the determinant of the sum (and can't really). That whole sum is just some matrix, whenever the denominators don't vanish anyway, so it has some determinant $y$ in the notation of my previous comment. You don't need to know what $y$ is in any real way, existence is enough. I think you need to take a step back from the algebraic manipulations you're hung up on and think more about what the equations and terms "mean".

Answer (score 2):

If $t\neq1,2$ then your displayed equation demonstrates an inverse for $tI-A$. Hence such $t$ cannot make $tI-A$ singular, that is cannot be eigenvalues.